# How would one say, "Publish your work in English"?

Tags: expression

I hope this is appropriate to post in this community.
I am constructing a Facebook ad for German professors in the social and behavioral sciences. The ad will be in English, but I want the heading to be in German, and I'd like it to say something like, "Publish your work in English," or "Publish your manuscript in English," depending on what sounds most natural. (The service being offered is language editing, which will be described further in the body of the ad.) 
Suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me an ad addressing people to publish their works in English **should be in English**. To make sure only those who are able to do it. So you have to make sure your service is recognized as a translation service, not as a publishing service. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Thank you, Janka. It is actually not a translation service; it is an editing service. Many German academics speak English quite fluently, but when they write for publication, their language is not quite up to the standard that journals require. The service involves having someone with both scientific knowledge in the field and native English editing capabilities. The ad will be in English; I only want the title of it to be in German.

Comment: You should express that then. Germans like it direct and precise. If you know their problem, tell them you know their problem. That's why German ads seem so univiting and odd to people outside. Just translating an existing slogan wouldn't help. Try "Publizieren in U.S.-Journals? Wir bringen ihre englischsprachigen Texte auf muttersprachliches Niveau!" *Publishing in U.S.-Journals? We make your English texts sound as written by a native speaker.*

Comment: @Janka: Ich denke Marketingberatung ist hier off topic.

Comment: Nanu, eine schlichte Übersetzungsanfrage ohne Vorarbeiten und sie wird nicht geschlossen?

Comment: @user unknown: genau deshalb hab ich das als Kommentar und nicht als Antwort verfasst. Bittedanke.

Comment: I don't need marketing advice -- I need translation/usage advice. Many thanks to those who gave their time and effort to respond!

Answer (score 5):

> Publizieren Sie Ihre Arbeit (Ihr Manuskript) auf Englisch!

oder

> Publizier deine Arbeit (dein Manuskript) auf Englisch!

Ob Arbeit, Manuskript, Text oder etwas anderes am besten geeignet ist, hängt von Publikum und den Umständen ab. *Du* ist gegenüber Kindern üblich, im Geschäftsverkehr siezt man sich i.d.R. - es wird aber Mode, auch hier zu duzen, das hängt aber sehr vom Genre ab. Im Zweifelsfall sind *Sie* und *Text* geeignet, da neutral. 
*Text* ist sehr nüchtern und formal. *Arbeit* klingt ein wenig nach Mühe, aber in Deutschland wird man durch Arbeit geadelt, Fußballer rühmen sich nach hinten zu arbeiten wo andere belieben, vorne zu zaubern. 
*Manuskript* ist etwas gehobener - würde aber in vielen künstlerischen oder akademischen Kreisen kein Wimpernzucken verursachen. Will man eingebildete Aufschneider ansprechen, ist Manuskript sicher eine gute Wahl.

Comment: What a thoughtful response! I appreciate it very much. And this part made me chuckle: "Will man eingebildete Aufschneider ansprechen, ist Manuskript sicher eine gute Wahl."

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using

> "Veröffentlichen Sie Ihre Arbeit auf Englisch!"

"Veröffentlichen" is a more common and neutral term than the loanword "publizieren". But it is also absolutely correct to use "publizieren" for texts, manuscripts, articles, research papers etc. It's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

If you offer to publish a book:

> Veröffentlichen Sie Ihre Arbeit auf Englisch!

If you just want to help with the text:

> Schreiben Sie Ihre Arbeit auf Englisch!

If you want to help with scientific papers:

> Publizieren Sie Ihre Papers auf Englisch!

If you want to keep it short:

> Publizieren Sie englisch!

Use "du" just if you want to address students only, e.g. to publish the master thesis

> Veröffentliche deine Arbeit auf Englisch!
>
> Schreibe deine Arbeit auf Englisch!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in thanking you, Leonard Michlmayr. I really appreciate your help!